# Is there an easy way to populate SlugField from CharField?

Tags: python, django, slug

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

Is there a built-in way to get the slug field to autopopulate based on the title? Perhaps in the Admin and outside of the Admin.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

for Admin in Django 1.0 and up, you'd need to use

```
prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',), }
```

in your admin.py

Your key in the prepopulated_fields dictionary is the field you want filled, and the value is a tuple of fields you want concatenated.

Outside of admin, you can use the `slugify` function in your views. In templates, you can use the `|slugify` filter.

There is also this package which will take care of this automatically: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields

Answer (score 9):

Thought I would add a complete and up-to-date answer with gotchas mentioned:

### 1. Auto-populate forms in Django Admin

If you are only concerned about adding and updating data in the admin, you could simply use the [prepopulated_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) attribute

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

### 2. Auto-populate custom forms in templates

If you have built your own server-rendered interface with forms, you could auto-populate the fields by using either the [|slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify) tamplate filter or the [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) utility when saving the form (is_valid).

### 3. Auto-populating slugfields at model-level with django-autoslug

The above solutions will only auto-populate the slugfield (or any field) when data is manipulated through those interfaces (the admin or a custom form). If you have an API, management commands or anything else that also manipulates the data you need to drop down to model-level.

[django-autoslug](https://pypi.org/project/django-autoslug/) provides the AutoSlugField-fields which extends SlugField and allows you to set which field it should slugify neatly:

```
class Article(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
```

**The field uses pre_save and post_save signals to achieve its functionality so please see the gotcha text at the bottom of this answer.**

### 4. Auto-populating slugfields at model-level by overriding save()

The last option is to implement this yourself, which involves overriding the default save() method:

```
class Article(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### NOTE: Bulk-updates will bypass your code (including signals)

This is a common miss-understanding by beginners to Django. First you should know that the pre_save and post_save signals are directly related to the save()-method. Secondly the different ways to do bulk-updates in Django all circumvent the save()-method to achieve high performance, by operating directly on the SQL-layer. This means that for the example model used in solution 3 or 4 above:

- Article.objects.all().update(title='New post') will **NOT** update the slug of any article
- Using [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) or [bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) on the Article model will **NOT** update the slug of any article.
- Since the save()-method is not called, **no pre_save or post_save signals will be emitted**.

To do bulk updates and still utilize code-level constraints the only solution is to iterate objects one by one and call its save()-method, which has drastically less performance than SQL-level bulk operations. You could of course use triggers in your database, though that is a totally different topic.

Comment: What is 'Job' in option 4?

Comment: @KovyJacob fixed by someone else

Answer (score 6):

Outside the admin, see [this django snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/690/). Put it in your `.save()`, and it'll work with objects created programmatically. Inside the admin, as the others have said, use `prepopulated_fields`.

Comment: I agree, but watchout the bulk insertion... The save() method is not directly called.

Answer (score 3):

For pre-1.0:

```
slug = models.SlugField(prepopulate_from=('title',))
```

should work just fine

For 1.0, use [camflan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141487/is-there-an-easy-way-to-populate-slugfield-from-charfield#141554)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use pre_save django signal to populate slug outside of django admin code.
See [Django signals documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/).

Ajax slug uniqueness validation will be useful too, see [As-You-Type Slug Uniqueness Validation @ Irrational Exuberance](http://lethain.com/entry/2008/sep/26/as-you-type-slug-uniqueness-validation/)

Comment: I wonder with this method if this work with bulk insertion? I'm not sure :/

Comment: you have to make a workaround for bulk operation, you can check this thread for some insights http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744795/django-emulate-database-trigger-behavior-on-bulk-insert-update-delete

Answer (score 2):

```
prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',), }
```

Comment: i think this will help you

Comment: You should try to explain the intention of your code, even if it's trivial for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Auto-populating slugfields at model-level with the built-in django slugify:**

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Place:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug_name = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify as django_slugify

from v1 import models


@receiver(pre_save, sender=models.Place)
def validate_slug_name(sender, instance: models.Place, **kwargs):
    instance.slug_name = django_slugify(instance.name)
```

Credits to: https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug/blob/9e3992296544a4fd7417a833a9866112021daa82/autoslug/utils.py#L18

Answer (score 0):

[autoslug](https://bitbucket.org/neithere/django-autoslug) has worked quite well for me in the past. Although I've never tried using it with the admin app.