# Slug field error in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to integrate the following [Blog](http://api.rst2a.com/1.0/rst2/html?uri=http%3A//django-threadedcomments.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/tutorial.txt&style=zope) app to my site,I get the following error for the slug field ,how to resolve this issue

```
     TypeError at /login/

     __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prepopulate_from'

     Request Method:   GET
     Request URL:   http://192.168.254.35/accounts/login/new_wind/
     Django Version:   1.2.1 SVN-1957
     Exception Type:   TypeError
     Exception Value:

     __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prepopulate_from'
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class BlogPost(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  slug = models.SlugField(prepopulate_from=('title',))
  body = models.TextField()
  published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

class Admin:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says it all: a `SlugField` does not take the keyword argument `prepopulate_from`. [The docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) back this up - it only takes the argument `max_length` in addition to the standard argument. This should be done [in the admin class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) instead.

**Edit**: So your model file would be:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class BlogPost(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  slug = models.SlugField()
  body = models.TextField()
  published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

and the admin.py file for the same application would be:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import BlogPost

class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

admin.site.register(BlogPost, BlogPostAdmin)
```

If you don't understand how the admin site works, see [Part 2 of the official Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/).

Comment: I havedjango/django/contrib/auth/admin.py but what is that has to be chnaged in this..

Answer (score 1):

It seems the way to prepopulate has been updated in django, see this question: [Is there an easy way to populate SlugField from CharField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141487/is-there-an-easy-way-to-populate-slugfield-from-charfield)

Comment: @thomas88:I havedjango/django/contrib/auth/admin.py but what is that has to be changed in this.From the post i didnt get what that needs to be changed

Comment: I don't have a django handy, but I think Blairs answer is correct except prepopulate_from=('title',) should be removed, if I interpret the docs correctly.