# Error when autocreating slug in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my model:

```
class post (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=75000)
    picture = models.URLField(max_length=200, default="https://i.ibb.co/0MZ5mFt/download.jpg")
    show_date = models.DateTimeField()
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        to_slug = f"{self.title} {self.show_date}"
        self.slug = slugify(to_slug)
        super(Job, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I run my website and try to add an item from the admin portal, though, I get this:

```
NameError at /admin/blog/post/add/
name 'Job' is not defined
```

I got the autoslugging part from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141487/is-there-an-easy-way-to-populate-slugfield-from-charfield#:%7E:text=4.%20Auto%2Dpopulating%20slugfields%20at%20model%2Dlevel%20by%20overriding%20save()), what is 'Job' that I have to define?

Comment: This is why copy-paste code from internet without understanding it is a bad idea. `Job` is a class. Where is this class defined? I don't know. It's probably fixed by some `import` statement which wasn't included in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is `post`, not `Job`, so your `super(…)` call should be `super(post, self)`, but as of [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), you do not need to specify the name, so you can work with:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=75000)
    picture = models.URLField(max_length=200, default='https://i.ibb.co/0MZ5mFt/download.jpg')
    show_date = models.DateTimeField()
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        to_slug = f"{self.title} {self.show_date}"
        self.slug = slugify(to_slug)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`post`</s> to `Post`.

---

> **Note**: You can make use of [**`django-autoslug`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug) to automatically create a slug based on other field(s).

---

> **Note**: Normally you should *not* change slugs when the related fields change. As is written in the article [*Cool URIs don't change* <sup>[w3.org]</sup>](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI), URIs are *not* supposed to change, since these can be bookmarked. Therefore the slug should only be created when creating the object, not when you change any field on which the slug depends.